# Launching 32 bit executable from command prompt in Win 7 64 bit OS

Tags: windows-7, command-prompt, syswow64

I am working on Windows 7 64 bit and have a wierd problem. I installed installAnywhere(a 32 bit application) in c:\Programs(x86) since I did not want to install it in the regular "c:\Program Files(x86)" to avoid the hassles of space in directory.

When I attempted to call the installanywhere from command prompt using the syntax:
cmd /c "c:\Programs(x86)\InstallAnywhereEnterprise\build\build.exe" ...
I get the error "c:\Programs" is not a command. The reason being it is attempting to look to installAnywhere in c:\Programs ignoring the (x86) part.

I did some investigation on launching 32 bit programs  vs 64 bit programs from command prompt and tried using *%windir%\SysWow64\cmd.exe*. When I used "%windir%\SysWow64\cmd.exe",
the %programfiles% correctly points to "c:\Programs Files(x86)" but launching the command I mentioned just gives the same error. The *FileSystemRedirector* of Windows still 
keeps pointing to c:\Programs. I reinstalled InstallAnywhere in the default location "C:\Programs Files(x86)" but I dont know why it does not work with "C:\Programs(x86)".

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: This really just looks like you have an unquoted space in the command you're typing in. That's the only thing that would cause this error. Could you please verify that? Maybe post a screenshot of your command window?

Comment: Actual error message -
C:\>cmd /c "C:\Programs(x86)\InstallAnywhere 2011 Enterprise\build.exe"
'C:\Programs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen this issue before, but I just duplicated it. See my answer for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the parentheses.

```
"C:\Programs^(x86)\..."
```

Why exactly are you not ok with putting it in the regular Program Files directory? Space shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: As you said, I already installed to c:\Program Files(x86) and now it works. The originial regarding installing in c:\Programs(x86) seems to have been resolved with your answer. Now I get the message which looks reasonable from the command prompt - C:\>cmd /c "C:\Programs^(x86)\InstallAnywhere 2011 Enterprise\build.exe"
'C:\Programs(x86)\InstallAnywhere' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.